# Getting unique rows/values in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

Getting unique rows/values in SQL. I have same some data like this

```
valueA  ValueB    ValueC

test    "Value1"  "Something"

test    "Value1"  "Something else"

test2   "Value1"  "Something else"
```

So then I want to get the first two rows since valueC is different and then I also want row
3.

but say Row 4 is

```
test    "Value1"  "Something"
```

The same as Row 1.  I don't want that row.

Can I do this with a select statement or where or something else?

In my schema ValueA is in one table and then Values b and C are from a different table.
So I am doing something like

```
select * from table1,table2
```

which gives me the 3 values.

But I don't want the repeated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1, Table2
```

will do what you want.

However, your SELECT statement does not include an criteria to tell the system *how* to join the rows together. You will therefore get a cartesian product, containing a number of rows equal to the number of rows in Table1 times the number of rows in Table2.  This is generally *not* what you want (occasionally it is).

So you probably want something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1, Table2 WHERE Table1.SomeColumn = Table2.SomeColumn
```

or, in a more current dialect of SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.SomeColumn = Table2.SomeColumn
```

Comment: This is probably the best answer. I think I had some other data points that I did not have in my question. But this is a great answer based on my question as written.

Answer (score 1):

Use `SELECT DISTINCT` ?

As in:

```
SELECT DISTINCT value1, value2, value3 FROM table1, table2
```

Comment: I looked at distinct, like
"Select Distinct ValueC from Table2"
but then if you look at my example that would leave out row 3 where the ValueC is the same but Value A is not.

Comment: Ah, but you need to put all the columns you want to be distinct in the SELECT clause - so, not SELECT DISTINCT ValueC, but SELECT DISTINCT ValueA, ValueB, ValueC.

Answer (score 1):

Select Distinct * from table1, table2

Answer (score 1):

You might want to have a look to the SQL reference for:

- Unique
- Distinct
- Group By

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM table1, table2
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT * FROM Table1, Table2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select a.valueA, b.valueB, b.valueC
from table1 a join table2 b on <join condition>
group by a.valueA, b.valueB, b.valueC;
```